# TLS handshake parallelization

Tags: tls

As I understand, during TLS handshake phase, it is not legal for an endpoint to send its own handshake messages till the time it processes its peer's entire flight of messages completely. E.g. although a server is able to compute master secret after seeing client_key_exchange,

it cannot send its own change_cipher_spec and then finished messages

until it has processed client's finished message.

Why did the designers of TLS (say v1.2 and prior) disallow the possibility

of handshake messages flowing in parallel in both directions?

Comment: My feeling is that it is just to ensure that each end can compute the same value of handshake_hash used in processing finished message.

Comment: Your understanding is not fully correct. While this was defined in the TLS 1.2 RFC this way it is no longer true when [TLS False Start](https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/#enable-tls-false-start) is used.

Comment: Isn't the entire handshake process half duplex? That certainly helps with simplifying protocol implementations, even at the cost of some performance.

Comment: Also note that non-concurrent sending _may_ also make protocol analysis easier.

Comment: If a tls endpoint violates this half-duplex rule, i.e. starts sending its own records without fully consuming full flight of records from peer, is it detectable by the other end?

Comment: TCL is stateful; if one side produces something and it isn't consumed then the stream simply blocks. You can of course make *calculations* asynchronous in case enough information is present to perform them before the result is required.